# find extreme values of $\frac{2x}{x²+4}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am doing my homework like a good little boy. I know that when I want to find the extreme values of a function I have to put the derivative equal to zero so I can find the x values. I've done it before with easier functions where I only have to use the power rule.

But with the function

$\dfrac{2x}{x²+4}$

I think I have to use the quotient rule:

$f'(x)= \dfrac {2x²+4-(2x)^2} {(x²+4)^2} \implies f'(x)= \dfrac{-2x²+4}{(x²+4)^2}$

Is this correct? If it is, I think the following step would be

$\dfrac{-2x²+4}{x^4+8x²+16}=0$

I don't know how I can find the solutions to this... Any tips?

Comment: You should be careful with your parentheses.  $2(x^2+4)$ for instance. At the bottom, it looks complicated, but you can multiply out the denominator and it becomes very simple (of course, you should make a mental note that the denominator should not be zero, thankfully here it doesn't happen for real x)

Comment: Your derivative will be $\dfrac{8-2x^2}{(x^2+4)^2}$. This is $0$ when the numerator is $0$, namely at $x=\pm 2$.

Comment: A (minor) tip: When you use the Quotient Rule to find the derivative, you will end up with a $(g(x))^2$ at the bottom. Usually, that's very nice, leave it alone, don't expand it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks, I was always wondering why the answers on wolframalpha never expanded it :)

Comment: It's an old military proverb: don't volunteer! More seriously, you often need to know whether a derivative is positive or negative. A square $(g(x))^2$ is never negative, so you can concentrate on worrying about where the "top" is positive or negative.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lord_Farin someone editted it for me, I dont know any TeX yet. I'll spend some time learning it soon :)

Comment: My apologies, I should've checked. // @ParthThakkar please take note of my previous comment.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, taken!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You employed the quotient rule correctly, but because you omitted a necessary pair of parentheses in the numerator, you made an algebra error in simplifying it. You should have

$$f\,'(x)=\frac{2(x^2+4)-(2x)(2x)}{(x^2+4)^2}=\frac{2x^2+8-4x^2}{(x^2+4)^2}=\frac{8-2x^2}{(x^2+4)^2}\;.$$

Setting this to $0$ and solving is easier than it looks: assuming that the denominator is not $0$, **a fraction is** $\mathbf0$ **if and only if its numerator is** $\mathbf0$. Clearly $(x^2+4)^2$ is never $0$, since it’s always at least $16$, so

$$\frac{8-2x^2}{(x^2+4)^2}=0\quad\text{if and only if}\quad 8-2x^2=0\;,$$

and that’s an easy equation to solve.

Comment: Silly me, forgetting the parentheses =) isn't 2x²-4x² = -2x²?

Comment: @user1534664: It sure is; I typoed it and then kept copying the typoed version. Fixed now; thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an algebraic way without using calculus

$$\text{Let }y=\frac{2x}{x^2+4}\iff x^2y-2x+4y=0$$ which is a Quadratic equation in $x$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant of the above equation must   be $\ge0$

i.e, $(-2)^2\ge 4\cdot y\cdot 4y\iff y^2\le \frac14$

We know, $x^2\le a^2\iff -a\le x\le a$

---

Alternatively,  let $x=2\tan\theta$ which is legal as $x,\tan\theta$ can assume any real value

$$\implies\frac{2x}{x^2+4}=\frac{2\cdot 2\tan\theta }{(2\tan\theta)^2+4}=2\frac{ 2\tan\theta }{4(1+\tan^2\theta)}=\frac{\sin2\theta}2$$

Now, we know the range of $\sin2\theta$ for real $\theta$

Comment: The second method is awesome - new to me!