# If we know range of a function , how can construct range of other function?

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If we know $\frac{-1}{2}\leq \frac{x}{x^2+1}\leq \frac{1}{2}$ how can obtain the range of the function below?
>   $$y=\frac{4 x}{9x^2+25}$$

The problem is what's the range with respect to  $\frac{-1}{2}\leq \frac{x}{x^2+1}\leq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738388/determining-the-maximum-of-a-rational-function

Answer (score 4):

Write
$$\frac{4x}{9x^2+25}=\frac{4}{9x+\frac{25}{x}}$$ and use AM-GM in two cases:

1) $x>0$:
$$y\leq\frac{4}{2\sqrt{9x\cdot\frac{25}{x}}}=\frac{2}{15}.$$

2) $x<0$: $$y\geq-\frac{4}{2\sqrt{(-9x)\cdot\left(-\frac{25}{x}\right)}}=-\frac{2}{15}.$$
The equality occurs for $9x=\frac{25}{x}$ and since we have a continuous function,

we got the answer:
$$\left[-\frac{2}{15},\frac{2}{15}\right]$$

Comment: Its not written anywhere that $x>0$ ? How can we apply AM-GM

Comment: @Archis Welankar I added something. See now.

Comment: That makes sense now. :)

Answer (score 3):

$$y=\frac{4 x}{9x^2+25}\\y=\frac{4 x}{25(\frac{9}{25}x^2+1)}=\\y=\frac4{25}\frac{ x}{((\frac{3}{5}x)^2+1)}$$ now take $u=\frac{3x}{5}$
$$y=\frac4{25}\frac{ x}{((\frac{3}{5}x)^2+1)}=\\\frac4{25}\frac{ \frac{5}{3}u}{((u)^2+1)}=\\\frac{4}{15}\frac{u}{u^2+1}\\$$you know $\frac{-1}{2}\leq \frac{u}{u^2+1}\leq \frac{1}{2}$ so 
$$-\frac{4}{15}\times \frac {1}{2} \leq y=\frac{4}{15}\frac{u}{u^2+1} \leq \frac{4}{15}\times \frac {1}{2}$$

Comment: how is that a hint

Comment: first time it was hint ...i edit it next .i 'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
- \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{x}{x^2+1} \leq \frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $x= \frac{3z}{5}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
- \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{\frac{3z}{5}}{(\frac{3z}{5})^2+1} \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
- \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{15z}{9z^2+25} \leq \frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply by $  \frac{4}{15}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
- \frac{2}{15} \leq \frac{4z}{9z^2+25} \leq \frac{2}{15}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: This is the same approach as @Khosrotash, but you lost the $z^2$ in the term $9z^2$ in your last two inequalities.