# Find the domain of the function $f(x) =\frac{x+4}{x^2-9}$

Tags: functions, rational-functions

I need to find the domain of the function $\;f(x) =\dfrac{x+4}{x^2-9}.$

My answer was: $(-\infty, -3)\cup(3, \infty)$.

The book's answer was: $(-\infty, -3)\cup(-3,-3)\cup(3,+\infty)$

It's question 25 btw. Could the book have possibly made a mistake?[image]

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472169/find-extreme-values-of-frac2xx%C2%B24

Comment: Perhaps you could think of it as "all real numbers except $3$ and $-3$" and then compare with your answer and the book's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The book is right. It is not defined only for exactly two points, $\pm3$. I assume you meant $(-3,3)$ for the middle interval. It certainly is defined well for say $x=0, 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Your domain *excludes all values* **between and including** $-3$ and $3$. The only points to exclude are $x = -3, x=3$, and that's just what the book does although the middle interval should read $(-3, 3)$ (and not $(-3,-3)$, as you've typed it):

Domain: $$x \in (-\infty, -3)\cup (-3, 3) \cup (3, +\infty)$$

Test for yourself: pick a point in the interval $(-3, 3)$ and test it. You'll see the function is indeed defined there.

Another, perhaps simpler way to write the domain is as follows: $x\in \mathbb R - \{-3, 3\} = \mathbb R\setminus \{-3, 3\},\;$ essentially, "the domain consists of all real numbers except $-3$ and $3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2-9\neq 0\iff x\neq3,-3\iff x\in\mathbb R-\{3,3\}\iff$$
$$\iff x\in(-\infty,-3)\cup(-3,3)\cup(3,\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

Informally, the domain of the function is the set of all input values of the function. We can input any real number into this function, **except** $x=\pm3$ (in which case we're dividing by $0$, which is not allowed), so the domain is all real numbers that are not equal to $\pm 3$.

There are loads of different ways of writing $\text{dom}(f)$. e.g.

- $\mathbb{R} \setminus\{-3,3\}$
- $(-\infty,-3) \cup (-3,3) \cup (3,\infty)$ (the book's answer).

Your answer is wrong because you've forgotten about the numbers between $-3$ and $3$ (exclusive).